# Collapse src blocks in org-mode by default

Tags: org-mode

When I open an `org` file, I want all the `src` blocks to start collapsed and stay that way until I explicitly `org-cycle` them.

I can't find any variable to control this behavior. Perhaps I'm overlooking something? Or maybe someone has an elisp solution?

Comment: Here is a link to a related questions that talks about using the variable `org-hide-block-startup`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21563210/2112489.  And, the following link has something to do with cycling visibility of `src` blocks that I wrote up a while back in time, but it doesn't set them to be hidden by default.  I won't have time to work on this today or tomorrow, but here is the link in case you or anyone else wants to play a bit with the code:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25496350/2112489

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by adding the `org-hide-block-all` command to `org-mode-hook`:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-hide-block-all)
```

---

For my personal configuration, I've extended this solution a bit:

```el
(defvar org-blocks-hidden nil)

(defun org-toggle-blocks ()
  (interactive)
  (if org-blocks-hidden
      (org-show-block-all)
    (org-hide-block-all))
  (setq-local org-blocks-hidden (not org-blocks-hidden)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-toggle-blocks)

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c t") 'org-toggle-blocks)
```

With this in place, `org-mode` collapses `SRC` blocks by default **and** lets me toggle visibility of all `SRC` blocks by hitting <kbd>C-c t</kbd>. (If you decide to use this code you can of course adapt the key binding to your liking.)

Comment: i'm looking for a solution that read a metadata and collapses or not by default if metadata says so